# Finding $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)} \frac {xy - x } {x^2 + y^2 - 2y + 1} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to approach it using polar coordinates, but am not sure how to handle it because $r = 1$ instead of $r = 0$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit does not exist. Try $y = x+1$ and $y = 2x+1$ and $x\to 0$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Notice that the issue raised in the question is that the limit is *not* at the origin.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I meant the transformed limit of Dr. MV. Now, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}\frac{xy-x}{x^2+y^2-2y+1}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)}\frac{x(y-1)}{x^2+(y-1)^2}\\\\
&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just let $u=y-1$. Then
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,1)} \frac {xy - x } {x^2 + y^2 - 2y + 1}=\lim_{(x,u)\to(0,0)}\frac{xu}{x^2+u^2}.
$$
Given limit doesn't exist.